# Why am I getting error when I use Postman and oauth2 for login access case in apiagility?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, oauth-2.0, laminas-api-tools

I am new to Zend Framework 2. I am trying to get the login access scenario working with Postman (chrome extension). I have gone through the forum but I'm not sure if I'm missing something or not. So here are the steps that I have taken so far:
In MYSQL I have set up the tables accordingly and there is a user with the following fields in the `oauth_clients` table:

- `client_id` : `testclient`
- `client_secret` : `testpass`
- `redirect_uri` : `/oauth/receivecode` *(I'm not sure about the value of
  this one could someone please shed some light on this?)*
- `grant_type` : `password` *( I want to use the service for authentication
  and authorization to access a website or login access scenario)*

The rest of the fields are `NULL`. No other entries in other tables.
I set the parameters in Postman like this:

- `Authorization` : `Oauth2`

Headers:

- `Accept` : `application/json`
- `Content-Type` : `application/json`

The raw body is like:

```
{
    "client_id":"testclient",
    "client_secret":"testpass",
    "grant_type":"password"
}
```

I post the request to:
`www.dummy.dev/oauth/authorize`

When I post the request this is what I get:

```
{
  "type": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html",
  "title": "invalid_request",
  "status": 302,
  "detail": "Invalid or missing response type"
}
```

Why do I get this error message?

Comment: i don't see an actual question

Comment: I have edited the title to make it more clear. I get error if you see the very end of my post: "invalid missing response type". So what I'm wondering is a possible mistake in my DB or apigility setup etc that cases this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redirect uri is not necessary and could be left null in the database as well. The correct uri to POST is `www.dummy.dev/oauth` and the raw parameters in Postman are:

```
{
    "client_id":"dev.dummy",
    "username":"testclient",
    "password":"testpass",
    "grant_type":"password"
}
```

The value of password is stored and encoded (with bcrypt) in the database. `client_id` and `client_secret` are not important in this scenario as my own website is the client of my API.

Answer (score 0):

This error is triggered [here in the OAuth2 `AuthorizeController`](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Controller/AuthorizeController.php#L198).

The controller checks whether the `$response_type` is valid. If not it returns this error message.

On [line 313](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Controller/AuthorizeController.php#L313) you see:

```
protected function getValidResponseTypes()
{
    return array(
        self::RESPONSE_TYPE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        self::RESPONSE_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
    );
}
```

Those constants are defined [in the `AuthorizeControllerInterface`](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Controller/AuthorizeControllerInterface.php#L26):

```
const RESPONSE_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION_CODE = 'code';
const RESPONSE_TYPE_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'token';
```

So somewhere during the handling of your request this `$response_type` value is not set correctly. It should either be set as `token` or `code` for the request to validate correctly. Not sure where in your config you did something wrong but with this information you should be able to find the problem.